# How to find how many students passed both exams?

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

Here is my question

> In a class which has $36$ students, there are $26$ students who passed
>   math and $20$ students who passed physics exam and $4$ students
>   couldn't pass the both subjects.

Then, how do we find the students who passed the both exam?

Regards!

Comment: This is not really related to the group theory. But anyway, you can use inlcusion-exclusion formula: $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A \cap B|$.

Comment: @user340297 Can you show the solution for which you gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$36-4=32$ students passed one or the other.

$26+20-32=14$ passed both. See the diagram...

Hope it helps

$$...$$

[image]